# ReachabilityManager singleton class method not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, reachability

I'm trying to implement my ReachabilityManager singleton and check if the internet is reachable.  Unfortunately when I attempt to call the class methods I get this error.

[image]

To go through the checklist:

1) I have imported both the reachability and my manager into the tableView I'm working on.
[image]

2) I have implemented class methods in my singleton.
[image]

3) I've also instantiated the manager in the appDelegate.
[image]

So what am I missing?

Comment: Please update your question by replacing the code images with the actual (formatted) text of your code. It's actually easier to read and much easier to work with when providing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isReachable is a class method and you are trying to call a class method from an object of this class by doing so

```
[[InternetReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable] ;
```

in order for this to work you should call your class methods from the class itself without creating an object from the class like so :

```
[InternetReachabilityManager isReachable] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted you don't need to send a message for shared instance since isReachable is your class method. Just:

```
[InternetReachabilityManager isReachable]
```

should work.